# What does it mean for /proc/kpagecount to be zero

Tags: kernel, ram, proc

for some entries in /proc/kpagecount, all the 64 bit entry is zeros and yet the page is allocated (confirmed from /proc/kpageflags). What does it mean for kpagecount to be zero for certain physical pages? does that mean that a daemon process is using this memory?

Answer (score 0):

`proc/kpagecount` is a virtual file, when you read it, you get the result of executing function [`kpagecound_read()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/page.c#L29).

```c
static ssize_t kpagecount_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf,
                 size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
// ....
    u64 pcount;

    pfn = src / KPMSIZE;
    count = min_t(size_t, count, (max_pfn * KPMSIZE) - src);
    if (src & KPMMASK || count & KPMMASK)
        return -EINVAL;

    while (count > 0) {
        if (pfn_valid(pfn))
            ppage = pfn_to_page(pfn);
        else
            ppage = NULL;
        if (!ppage || PageSlab(ppage) || page_has_type(ppage))
            pcount = 0;
        else
            pcount = page_mapcount(ppage);

        if (put_user(pcount, out)) {
            ret = -EFAULT;
            break;
        }

        pfn++;
        out++;
        count -= KPMSIZE;

        cond_resched();
    }
// ...
}
```

and `page_has_type()` is.

```c
static inline int page_has_type(struct page *page)
{
    return (int)page->page_type < PAGE_MAPCOUNT_RESERVE;
}
```

If the entry for a page is zero in `kpagecount` and is allocated, it means:

1. It is used in slabs.
2. `page->page_type < PAGE_MAPCOUNT_RESERVE`  see [patch :return 0 for special pages that are never mapped](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/12/10/1005). This patch is quite new. Consider when this question is asked, I don't think it's the case.
3. `page_mapcount(page)` returns zero. some page are allocated but not mapped.
   I'am not sure why. Anyway, you can write kernel module/code that allocate page without create a mapping.